# How to click on a button (angular) via python script selenium

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium

I'm new to selenium, python and angular. I managed to run few tests with Python and selenium; however, I find it hard to click on a button when angularJS is involved. The code of the button is:

```
<button type="button"
        class="xyz"
        ng-click="validateList()"
        id="home-xyz-button">
  <i class="xyz-up"></i>Validate
</button>
```

I run the code:

```
browser.find_element_by_id("home-xyz-button").click()
```

and this does not work.

Comment: How does it not work?  If there is an exception, can you edit your question and add it?  It would also prove helpful to post a larger section of HTML, so that we could help you find a selector.  There's too many things I can think of that may be wrong:  ID appears multiple times.  ID is dynamic.  Element is contained in a frame.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work?

Answer (score -1):

Below is my script:

```
import os, sys
from selenium import webdriver

# Load the firefox driver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

# Open a browser and browser to website 
browser.get('link to the website')

browser.implicitly_wait(10)

# Select File for Validation
SelectFileForValidation = browser
  .find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class=\"row ng-scope\"]"+
                         "/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input")
if SelectFileForValidation is None:
    print('SelectFileForValidation is not found')
    exit(0)
else:
    print('SelectFileForValidation is found')
    SelectFileForValidation.click()

# Get the file name
FindTheUploadedFile = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class=\"row ng-scope\"]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div[@class=\"ng-binding\"]")
if FindTheUploadedFile is None:
    print('FindTheUploadedFile is not found')
    exit(0)
else:
    print('FindTheUploadedFile is found')
    print FindTheUploadedFile.text 

ValidateFileButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id=\"home-xyz-button\"]")
if ValidateFileButton is None:
    print('ValidateFileButton is not found')
    exit(0)
else:
    print('ValidateFileButton is found')
    ValidateFileButton.ng-click()


#browser.get('link to the site (used to refresh)')

exit(0)
```

The HTML code is:

```
<div class="111">
    <button type="button" class="222" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uploadFileModal" id="kkk">
        <i class="333"></i> Upload
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="xyz" ng-click="validateList()" id="home-xyz-button">
        <i class="xyz-up"></i> Validate
    </button>
    <button disabled="true" type="button" class="444" id="aaaa">
        <i class="555"></i> Download
    </button>
    <button disabled="true" type="button" class="666" id="bbbb">
        <i class="777"></i> Delete
    </button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="888" id="cccc" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="999">
            <div class="101010">
                <div class="11111">
                    <button type="button" class="121212" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h2 class="131313" id="dddd">Upload File</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="141414">
                    Browse to the file you intend to upload. <br> <br>
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="eee" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().storeFile(this)"> <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="fff> Overwrite existing file
                </div>
                <div class="151515">
                    <button type="button" class="161616" data-dismiss="modal" id="ggg">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="171717" id="hhh" ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Modal -->
</div>
```

The printout that I get is:

```
SelectFileForValidation is found
FindTheUploadedFile is found
"The file Name"
ValidateFileButton is found
```

But I can not see that the click() is being executed